# Creating a copy of a class with a different constructor

Tags: python

So I have a class Queen. I want to pass this instance into a function and within that function I want to create (based on which class is passed in could be Rook, King, etc) a new instance of Queen (or Rook or King) but with different initial input parameters. I hope that was simple

I can do this from a utility class but I want the functionality within the Board class.

```
# This part works if I do it in the utility class

board.removePiece(pos6)
board.removePiece(pos2)
board.placePiece(pos6, Queen("Black", pos6))

# This part doesnt work

def capturePiece(self, pieceA, pieceB):
    temp = pieceA
    pos = pieceB.position

    self.removePiece(pieceB.position)
    self.removePiece(pieceA.position)

    self.placePiece(pos, temp.create_another(temp.team, pos))

# From the Queen, King, etc, class

def create_another(self, team, position): # Returning constructor
    return type(self, team, position)()
```

Comment: Do you want to create a new **instance** or a new **class**? If it's an instance, you only have a bracketing error: `return type(self)(team, position)` should work

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to remove your pieces and create new ones when moving them around the board? Why not change the value of their position attribute to reflect the new position after the move? That way you can start with a fixed set of instances and don't have to worry about creating (and deleting) them. I might have missed something, but this seems unecessarily complicated to me.

Comment: Sorry I didnt clarify I want to create a new object (temp) but with different attributes.

Comment: @NathanielAbraham I got that, I just don't understand the reasoning :) In the end this appears to be chess, so there's no point in having two black queens in the same game, right?

Comment: @shmee You are completely right. This was the first way I thought of, and I feel Im too far down to look back. Im storing the pieces in a map and each piece uses its position to determine its valid moves - Yeah but what about promotions XD

Comment: @NathanielAbraham Well, pormotions obviously can result in the instantiation of a second queen (didn't even know about that mechanic until now :)). Still, changing the state of an instance (e.g. moving a piece to a new position) should not be done by instantiating a new object. You are basically creating static, non-changing objects. That's not really OOP and may come with caveats, as Serge outlined in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

That could be a good example for a class method on a base class:

```
class Piece:
    @classmethod
    def create_another(cls, team, position):
        return cls(team, position)
    def __init__(self, team, position):
        self.team = team
        self.position = position
    def __str__(self):
        return str("{} team {} at {}".format(self.__class__,
                             self.team, self.position))

class Queen(Piece):
    pass

class Rook(Piece):
    pass

class Board:
    def placePiece(self, pos, piece):
        print("Place {} at {}".format(piece, pos))
    def removePiece(self, position):
        print("Remove piece at " + str(position))
    def capturePiece(self, pieceA, pieceB):
        temp = pieceA
        pos = pieceB.position

        self.removePiece(pieceB.position)
        self.removePiece(pieceA.position)

        self.placePiece(pos, temp.create_another(temp.team, pos))
    def test(self):
        r = Rook("White", "d4")
        q = Queen("Black", "d6")
        self.capturePiece(q, r)
```

You can try:

```
b = Board()
b.test()
```

which displays as expected:

```
Remove piece at d4
Remove piece at d6
Place <class '__main__.Queen'> team Black at d4 at d4
```

But this is normally a poor design. Repeatedly destroying and creating new objects is much more expensive than simply changing their attributes. And anyway, on a *real* chessboard, you do not create new pieces, you move them, so you have no real reason not to just implement a move method to change the position on the Piece base class.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I will take this into account. Will this significantly slow down a game ?As playtime increases? I might restructure it now.

Comment: @NathanielAbraham: It will probably go unnoticed, but IMHO moving is just cleaner and simpler that a destroy-create_new pattern. Just avoid complexity when you can...